# HQL to get elements that possess all items in a set

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Currently, I have an HQL query that returns all Members who possess **ANY** Award from a set of specified Awards:

```
from Member m left join m.awards as a where a.name in ("Trophy","Ribbon");
```

What I now need is HQL that will return all Members who possess **ALL** Awards specified in the set of Awards.

So, assuming this data:

```
Joe has Trophy, Medal
Sue has Trophy, Ribbon
Tom has Trophy, Ribbon, Medal
```

The query above would return Joe, Sue, and Tom because all three possess at least one of Trophy or Ribbon. But I need to return only Sue and Tom, because they are the only ones who possess all of the specified awards (Trophy and Ribbon).

Here's the class structure (simplified):

```
class Member {
  private String name;
  private Set<Award> awards;
}
class Award {
  private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select m from Member m left join m.awards as a where a.name in ("Trophy","Ribbon") group by m having count(a)=2
```

Comment: @serg555 - Nice! Should it be count(a)=2 or count(2)>=2 ? Also, is there a way to do it without a group by/having clause? My actual query is quite complex and includes a where clause, order by clause, multiple subqueries and such. I also need to run the same query but with a count(*) to get the number of records returned. Running into trouble getting it all to work with the group by clause.

Comment: It should be `count(a)=2`. Sorry, I don't know alternate solution without grouping.

Comment: @serg555: ok, thanks. The problem I'm having is when I include group by/having in my count(*) query, I don't get a unique result. So countQuery.uniqueResult() fails. I need to get the total number of results for my pagination controls.

Comment: You can add distinct to the query. `select distinct m from Member m ...` or `select count(distinct m.id) from ...`

Comment: @serg555: That's exactly what I'm doing: `select count(distinct m.id) from ...`. But with the group by, `uniqueResults()` throws an exception. For instance, the regular query returns 4 member objects: `[Member, Member, Member, Member]`. The `count()` version of the query returns an array of 4 elements: `[1,1,1,1]`. I assume that is because each "group" has a size of 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just repeating myself...
The code to get the members that have EXACTLY the given collection of awards:

```
from Member m 
where not exists (
  from Award a where a.name in {"Trophy", "Ribbon"} 
  and a not in( 
    select * from Award a2 where a2.owner = m 
  ) 
) and not exists ( 
  from Award a3 where a3.owner = m and a3 not in {"Trophy", "Ribbon"} 
)
```

Comment: (So the answer to the original question is the first not-exists.)

Comment: One minor glitch with this: it works only with Award#names.
For example if you do the same thing with the set {"Trophy", "Handshake"} and there is no "Handshake"-named Award: it won't return an empty-result-set as expected, but a result as if with the one-element-set {"Trophy"} was the parameter.

Comment: (To correct this glitch: you'll need a table with all possible award-names and the first not-exist's should be "from" that entity. In native-sql a joined-union can solve this, in hql: we didn't find better)

Answer (score 0):

You can force distinct results by adding a DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY result transformer to the query call, IE:

```
getSession().createQuery(hql).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

I'm having a similar problem, but what I need to do is (following your example) to select all the members, who posess ALL of the awards and no more. So in your example the only correct result would be Sue. Any ideas?