# Using HibernateTemplate.find(...) with a String[] 

Tags: java, sql, string, hibernate, hql

I'm having troubles with HQL again :(

My desired SQL is this:

```
select employee.idemployee as id, employee.age as age,     
employee.birthday as birthday, employee.firstName as firstName, 
employee.gender as gender, employee.lastName as lastName from employee 
employee
inner join employee_skillgroups skillgroup1 on 
employee.idemployee=skillgroup1.idemployee
inner join employee_skillgroups skillgroup2 on
employee.idemployee=skillgroup.idemployee
where skillgroup1.idskillgroup =  'Sprachen'
and skillgroup.idskillgroup = 'SoftSkills'
```

But i just can't get HQL to generate me this ...
"Sprachen" and "SoftSkills" are two string coming out of a String[] I'm giving the method as a parameter. The method currently looks like this:

```
public List<Employee> findEmployeeWithTwoSkillGroups(final String[] skillGroups) {
return template.find("from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in ?", Arrays.asList(skillGroups).toString
    ().substring(1, Arrays.asList(skillGroups).toString().length()-1));
}
```

I "cast" the array to a list, execute `toString()` on it (so i get "[Sprachen, SoftSkills]") and cut off the first and the last char (so i get "Sprachen, SoftSkills").
I guess the problem is that HQL generates "[...].idskillgroup in ('Sprachen, SoftSkills')", like it treats the two strings like ONE string ...
And i just can't get it to work like i want it to :/

Can someone please help me and give me a hint what to try/do next? :-)

Greetz
gilaras

Simmilar question:

#### [HQL to get elements that possess all items in a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879161/hql-to-get-elements-that-possess-all-items-in-a-set)

Comment: Thanks for editing, i was just trying to find out how to do a line break in the code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a prepared statement, not string concatenation. It handles ('Sprachen, SoftSkills') like a single string because it *is* a single string. You want to insert a collection in your query. I'm not sure how to do this in hibernateTemplate, but hibernate itself supports adding a collection. see [the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 1):

The proper HQL statement should go more or less like this:

```
from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in ( 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz' )
```

so you are missing the ' ' for each word.

EDIT: Now that I got what you want to achieve here :-)

I would recommend you doing this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
     "from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in (:skillGroups)");
// skillGroups must be a Collection type
query.setParameterList("skillGroups", skillGroups); 
List list = query.list();
```

In case you need your result to be the `AND` of all elements of your `String[]` array, you can do the following:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
     "from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in (:skillGroups) group by e having count(s) = :skillGroupsLength");
query.setParameterList("skillGroups", skillGroups);
query.setParameter("skillGroupsLength", skillGroups.length);
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's right, but the question was like how do i get Hibernate to generate this, giving in an String[] ;-) I don't have the single words and actually i don't know for how much skillgroups a user would be searching for (so the could be just one String, two, three, four, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's the right answer to the question I asked first, but I got a little confused and copied the wrong SQL ._.  The problem is finding all employees having ALL skillgroups ... so there has to be an AND (IN gives me kind of an OR) ... Could you answer that question too? :D

Comment: You should really look into the HQL reference bro. It's all there. According to doc, for the AND you can use smth. like this: `s = all elements(:skillGroups)`

Comment: I read the reference through and through, didn't find anything that solved my problem.   Thats why i asked here ;-)   When i do it the way you said, i get `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found ':' near line 1, column 110 [from my.package.employeeweb.base.employee.Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s IN (all elements(:skillGroups))]`

Comment: Don't use the `IN (all elements ...))`. but `s = all elements(...)`

Comment: Agree, `all elements` does not work. However, I've spend some time on this problem and here's my soultion: `from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in (:skillGroups) group by e having count(s) = :skillGroupsLength`. This means you need to pass an additional parameter with the lenght of your `String[]` array. This works well on my box! ;-)