# HQL or SQL query to get data from many to many related entities

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using spring with hibernate to store data in MySql database. I am trying to retrieve rows based on filters requested by the user.
I have the following tables/entities : Product and Gemstone

**Relations:**

- Product many2many Gemstone

*I am trying to write a query to get products that have Gemstone A and Gemstone B and Gemstone C.. and so on.*

**Use Case:**

If user is asking for a product with gemstones 51 and 46. Query should only return product id 4.

**Query:**

filterGemstones() method return the gemstone user wants to filter products to. Using the below query I get zero records but if I remove `HAVING Count(DISTINCT p.product_id) = 2` I get product id 4, 5

[image: two muppets]

- HQL :

  ```
  createQuery("select p.productId from Product p JOIN p.gemstones g where g in :gemstones group by p having count (distinct p) =" +  filterGemstones().size() ).setParameter("gemstones",filterGemstones());
  ```
- SQL generate by hibernate :

  ```
  SELECT p.product_id 
  FROM   product p 
  INNER JOIN gemstone_product gp 
         ON p.product_id = gp.product_id 
  INNER JOIN gemstone g 
         ON gp.gemstone_id = g.gemstone_id 
  WHERE  g.gemstone_id IN ( 51, 46 ) 
  GROUP  BY p.product_id 
  HAVING Count(DISTINCT p.product_id) = 2
  ```

#### Product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private long productId;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "gemstone_product",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "gemstone_id")}
    )
    private Set<Gemstone> gemstones = new HashSet<>(0);

// setters and getters
}
```

#### Gemstone class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gemstone")
public class Gemstone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "gemstone_id")
    private long gemstoneId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "gemstone_product",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "gemstone_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")}
    )
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>(0);

// setters and getters
}
```

Comment: this works if user is filtering with just one gem and one metal but doesn't if multiple gems and metals

Comment: You need to use `join fetch` instead of just `join` since the collections are lazily loading, That is why you don't see any results

Comment: Result is still zero with join fetch. the current query with just join works if I ask for just one gem or just one metal or just one gem and one metal.

Comment: If you are passing objects as parameters use equal instead of in eg `where g=:gemstone1` or better keep in and pass a list instead as a parameter of the 2 objects e.g `setParameter("gemstones", List.of(gem1,gem2))`

Comment: Please see my edit the other query that i tried.  I tried passing the list but it gives me result with using OR condition between the values in the list. I need data with AND condition between all the values in the list.

Comment: Edited the post with my latest try and cleaned up the question

Comment: Why should the query returns only product[4], product[5] also has gemstones with ids 46,51, So it is true that the query without using having clause returns these 2 products 

BTW, The problem of using having clause that you are grouping by product id and expect to have more than product that is a contradiction, so I guess you meant to use `GROUP  BY g` instead of `p` but like I said before you don't need using having at all

Comment: Make sure to use `select distinct(p.productId)` so that you don't have any duplicates

Comment: That is the ask, a query that would return product[4] only because product[5] has an extra gemstone in it. Thanks for you suggestion. I will give it a try when I get back home in evening.

Comment: see this post similar case to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879161/hql-to-get-elements-that-possess-all-items-in-a-set

Answer (score 1):

Actually the SQL query that we need here is pretty simple:

```
SELECT t1.product_id 
FROM gemstone_product AS t1 
WHERE (t1.gemstone_id IN ?1 )  # (51, 46)
GROUP BY  t1.product_id  
HAVING (COUNT(t1.gemstone_id) = ?2) # 2 - # of items
```

It's a bit frustrating that it's not easy to create it with JPA, but it can be done with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) (produces the query above):

```java
public List<Integer> getProductsContainingAllStones(List<Long> gemstoneIds) {
    int count = gemstoneIds.size();

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Gemstone gemstone,
                                       JoinTable<Gemstone, Product> gemstoneProduct) -> {

        discardSQL(gemstoneProduct.join(gemstone, Gemstone::getProducts));

        long productId = gemstoneProduct.getInverseJoined().getProductId();
        long gemstoneId = gemstoneProduct.getJoined().getGemstoneId();

        SELECT(productId);
        FROM(gemstoneProduct);
        WHERE(gemstoneIds.contains(gemstoneId));
        GROUP(BY(productId));
        HAVING(COUNT(gemstoneId) == count);
    });
    return query.createQuery(em).getResultList();
}
```

More details on how it works can be found [here](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration#manytomany).